# Power equivalent to powercfg requests

Tags: powershell, powercfg

Is there an equivalent in powershellto

```
powercfg -requests
```

listing the processes preventing the sleeping ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options).

The function that you are searching for should be:

```
powercfg /requests
```